# Creating a calculated column

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I want to create a calculated column. I have measures, and I want to visualize this calculated column using my already created measures.

I want my calculated column to look like below

[image]

**All Groups**    --> (when I visualize the column with measures for this row, the measure value should show the sum of Group1 + Group2 + Group3)

I am using the expression below to create the calculated column, but it's not giving me the expected results.

NewColumn=  var g1 = account no=3 var g2 = account no in { 4, 5, 6} && account group <> 20 var g3= account group = 20 return SWITCH(TRUE(),g1,"Group1",g2,"Group2",g3,"Group3", g1 || g2 || g3, "All Groups" )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have more that 1 value in the same column so you can't have a column with group1 and All Groups value.
Maybe you can just use your colum group in a filter on a report and activate the option select all that will simulate your 'All groups'

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I am having. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: i'm not sure that I properly understand what you want. Why would you absolutely want to get the 'all value' in a column and not use the option directly in the report filter ?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by using the option directly in the report filter.
I have a tabular model cube, and I analyze data with Excel.

Comment: If you are in Excel you can just use the "total for row" in the power pivot option. that will return the evaluation of your measures for all the groups

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have other groups that are not mentioned in my post.
such as Group4, Group5, Group6 and AllGroup2 (which is the sum of Group4, Group5, and Group6)

So if I use total, it will give me the sum of all groups.

Comment: not the sum under every third group.

Comment: Ha ok then i think that you need to add a new column that just say if the line is part of this 3 groups or not and use this column as filter

Comment: if you create a separate table you can have such logic, otherwise you will need to add aggregated rows to your data